# Laurent series question

Tags: laurent-series

Determine the Laurent expansion about $z_0=0$ for
$$g(z)=\frac1{(z-1)(z-3)} \text{ on } \left\{z\in\mathbb C:1<\lvert z\rvert<3\right\}$$

I'm currently trying to solve this question, I have work out the solution to be 
$$-\frac{1}{2} \bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{3^{n+1}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^{n}} \bigg)   $$
could someone confirm if this is correct.

***Extension!***

Find the Laurent expansion about $0$ of 
$$f(z)=\frac1{(z-i)(z-2)}$$
on the following annlui: $0<|z|<1$

I'm not too sure how to solve this, I've found that for $|z|<1$ we have $$i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{z}{i}\bigg)^n$$
however, how would I find the summation for $|z|>0$?

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for my mistake, I had misread or forgotten to read the entire question.

Comment: on the second part where you wrote $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$, does this not consider $|z|<1$ whereas we're looking for $|z|>1$?

Comment: Correct, I had forgotten to read where you wished it to converge. Your solution seems fine.

Comment: awesome! thank you :D, could I add a separate question as an extension to this as I don't fully understand how to find the convergence?

Comment: Its been a while since I've done this, but a few questions to clarify the extension. For finding the series that converges on $|z|<1$ for $f(z)$ will include zero. I'm not certain as to why we wish to find it on the punctured disk $0<|z|<1$ since it is analytic at 0. I am not certain if that what was meant or not.

Also, I have arrived at a different series for $f(z)$ on $|z|<1$. I just wish to clarify the first point before reviewing this part.

Comment: I used partial fractions to get $\frac{1}{i-2}\bigg(\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z-2}\bigg)$ therefore $\frac{1}{z-i}=i\bigg(\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{i}}=i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{z}{i}\bigg)^n\bigg)$

Comment: I agree with the work here, but we still need to find the series for $-\frac{1}{z-2}$ for $|z|<1$ then add it to what we already know. I believe that should do it, aside from the fact that it converges at $z=0$ as well.

Comment: of courseeee!!! i was just being silly, thank you!